# Como usar AJAX com Laravel?

Tags: php, javascript, laravel-4, ajax

Tenho um select que quando eu mudar o valor dele ele deve reordenar uma lista, ex.: por id, nome, etc. sem o Laravel eu usaria uma função `onchange` e passaria o padrão de ordenação pra uma página PHP que iria imprimir essa lista ordenada pra mim...

Mas como fazer isso com o Laravel? Vou ter que gerar uma *view*? Tentei mas não consegui...

Estava tentando aqui acho que estou errando na hora gerar as views..

eu tenho uma view de layout que tem um `@yeld ('content')`, no caso eu precisaria atualizar só esse content, porém, quando eu faço:

```
$this->layout->content = View::make('usuarios.index', $variaveis);
```

ele duplica meu layout dentro da div content

//Segue o controller

```
   if(Request::ajax()){
       $usuarios = Usuario::orderBy(Input::get('order'),'ASC')->get();
       $variaveis = array('usuarios' => $usuarios);
       return View::make('usuarios.index', $variaveis);;
   }else{
       $usuarios = Usuario::orderBy('id','ASC')->get();
       $variaveis = array('usuarios' => $usuarios);
       $this->layout->content = View::make('usuarios.index', $variaveis);
   }
```

Porem ele nunca esta entrando o Request::ajax() e eu não consigo descobrir o porque

Comment: posta parte do teu código ai.

Comment: Editei a minha resposta para te explicar como ttu faz baseado no teu código.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Só vai entrar em `Request::ajax()` quando a requisição for feita via Ajax! :-)

Mas, atenção: isso é verificado através do cabeçalho HTTP `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH`. Esse *header* é enviado automaticamente em requisições Ajax feitas pelo jQuery e outras bibliotecas JavaScript, mas se você não está usando precisa acrescentá-lo para que o Laravel reconheça que a chamada é Ajax:

```
XHR.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XmlHttpRequest");
```

---

Outra alternativa é usar funções diferentes no Controller: uma para Ajax outra para requisições normais, e deixar de fora o `if (Request::ajax())`

Comment: esse XHR seria o objeto xmlhhtp?

Comment: coloquei logo após do open mais o laravel ainda não identifica como ajax

Comment: consegui cara vlw ai na verdade o header necessário é esse

OBJETO.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");

Answer (score 3):

Teu problema não é com laravel. Tu tens que fazer a mesma coisa, pega os eventos com javascript e monta o resultado da mesma forma que tu fazia antes do laravel.

No laravel tu vai pegar a tua função que faz o select e fazer algo mais ou menos assim

```
public function getConsulta()
{
   //tua consulta normal...  

   if (Request::ajax()) 
   {
      return Response::json($dados);
   }
}
```

No javascript que tu deve pegar esse json e tratar para fazer o update na tabela

Como tu esta retornando todo a tua view e renderizando toda ela, tu pode fazer assim no teu layout

@if(!Request::ajax())

```
   // teu código normal quando não é ajax
```

@else

```
   @yield('content') // isso vai fazer renderizar só a tua view
```

@endif

É necessário fazer isso porque tu ta dando um extends na tua view

no teu controller tu vai até poder mudar deixando ele assim

```
   $usuarios = Usuario::orderBy(isset(Input::get('order'))?Input::get('order'):'id','ASC')->get();
   $variaveis = array('usuarios' => $usuarios);
   return View::make('usuarios.index', $variaveis);;
```

Vai funcionar para tuas duas situações, quando for ou não ajax.

Comment: Então eu estou tentando retornar uma view o problema é que ele esta retornando o layout junto onde não era pra retornar..

vou editar com o codigo do controller pra vc dar uma olhada

Comment: então o problema esta nesse

 return View::make('usuarios.index', $variaveis);

não consigo retornar só isso ele não aparece nada e se eu mando assim

$this->layout->content = View::make('usuarios.index', $variaveis);

ele duplica o layout, tem outra coisa ele tbm não ta ordenando só ta recarregando...

Comment: o meu Input::get() ta sempre vindo null, como faço pra ele pegar os dados via post?

Comment: só conseguindo pegar os dados quando envio via get

Comment: Tu viu a parte que tu tem que mudar no teu layout?

Comment: sim eu mudei isso
 olha como ficou

http://pastebin.com/VTVSqdV2

Comment: acho que é o que o J. Bruni comentou deve estar faltando o header

Comment: porem não consigo fazer o laravel identificar como ajax

Comment: muito obrigado pela a ajuda daniel consegui fazer do jeito que tu falou estava faltando somente o header pra explicitar que era um requisição ajax

Comment: Blz, que bvom que conseguiu

Answer (score 2):

Eu não entendo de `lavarel`, trabalho com o `zend` e imagino que funciona basicamente da mesma forma, no ajax, você vai ter que fazer algum tipo de requisição para ter esse retorno, ou seja, no seu `controller` vai ser necessário cria uma `action` somente para atender essa requisição, e um view para montar o conteúdo...seu eu estivesse fazendo no zend, eu teria que dar um `disable layout` para que ele utilize somente o  conteúdo da view específica, provavelmente no lavarel isso também tem que ser feito...

Answer (score 0):

É basicamente a mesma coisa, basta trocar os diretórios e inserir o token no envio do formulario, segue um exemplo do que implementei aqui:

```
$.ajax({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-Token': $('input[name="_token"]').val()
    },
    type: 'GET',
    url: "{{ URL::to(teste/ajax) }}",
    data: 'nome='+$('input[name="nome"]').val(),
    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
    success: function(data){
        $(location).attr('href', "{{ URL::to(Request::path()) }}");
    },
    error: function(){
        alert('Erro no Ajax !');
    }
});
```